# Comparing the impact of crash between two objects: Free Fall vs Wind Mill

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, rotational-dynamics, collision, drag

1. Object A falls down to the ground directly without any other variable affecting it, which is free fall.
2. Object B falls down to the ground as the same trajectory with object A, while spinning around 360 degrees as windmill.

All else conditions being equal, which object gets more damaged (or impacted) by its crash to the ground?

If there is a clear answer it would be great if I could see the explanation in mathematical notations so that I could refer to the explanation for further studies.

Comment: Comment about terminology: A fall with drag/air resistance is by definition not a free fall.

Comment: @Qmechanic: Thank you for the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic principle here is the work-energy theorem which states that the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy $\Delta KE$, or

$$W_{net}=F_{ave}d=\Delta KE$$

Where $F_{ave}$ is the average impact force and $d$ is the stopping distance.

Assuming both your objects come to a stop when they impact the ground, more net work would be required to bring an object to a stop if it possessed both rotational kinetic energy in addition to translational kinetic energy prior to impact. Thus the average impact force/torque will be greater if the object impacts with both translational and rotational KE.

Whether or not that means there will be more damage depends on many other variables associated with the characteristics of the object that impacts the ground and the characteristics of the ground.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It helped a lot. Thanks!

Comment: @user281 Glad it helped you.